# Screenshot effect Android

Tags: java, android

i want to create an screen efect like when you take an screenshot in the phone, i mean, a little flash in the screen when i click a button, also i want to change the color of that flash. Is that posible? thank you very much in advance ;)

Comment: i tried to create a TransitionDrawable, i look for the part of the animation here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/systemui/screenshot/GlobalScreenshot.java#GlobalScreenshot.createScreenshotDropInAnimation%28%29 and i don't know how to search in english sites, cause i looked for "flash secreen" and i only found things about Flash and Android.

Answer (score 14):

An easy way to get this effect would be to have the following:

Create an empty 'panel' over your layout. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <!-- Your normal layout in here, doesn't have to be a LinearLayout -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnlFlash"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="[Set to your desired flash colour, image, etc]"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

The FrameLayout with the id 'pnlFlash' remains hidden away so it won't interfere with normal interaction.

Now when you want to make a flash all you have to do is make the panel appear for as long as is appropriate. having a nice fade off always helps too.

```
pnlFlash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

AlphaAnimation fade = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fade.setDuration(50);
fade.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
        pnlFlash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    ...
});
pnlFlash.startAnimation(fade);
```

I haven't used this kind of code before for a flash so you might want to tweak the duration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for Kotlin, as you will need to implement the Animation listener yourself.

```
private fun pictureTakenAnimation() {
    val listener = AnimationListener(pnlFlash)
    pnlFlash.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val fade = AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
    fade.setDuration(500);
    fade.setAnimationListener(listener)
    pnlFlash.startAnimation(fade);
}

inner class AnimationListener(val v : View) : Animation.AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
        v.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
        v.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add View.VISIBLE instead of View.GONE onAnimationEnd.

```
fade.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
...
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
    pnlFlash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
...
});
pnlFlash.startAnimation(fade);
```